# Проблема с заливкой графика

Tags: r

Датафрейм USmelanoma (пакет HSAUR3) содержит данные о смертности белых мужчин от злокачественной меланомы в 1950-1969 в разных штатах США (кроме Гавайских островов). Постройте такой график ядерной плотности смертности, как на приведенном рисунке, и сохраните его в переменную gg_mel. Используйте цвет "darkorange".
В коде решения на Stepik пакет и данные загружать не нужно, данные уже находятся в переменной USmelanoma.
Обратите внимание на форму распределения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение:

> gg_mel<-ggplot(data=USmelanoma,
>   aes(x=mortality))+geom_density(aes(fill ='darkorange'))+theme_dark()
>
> Error: Использован не тот цвет заливки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Визуально видно, что цвета разные, однако использован цвет по требованию задания - "darkorange". Подскажите в чем дело.

Comment: пожалуйста, не вставляйте в свои вопросы неработающие ссылки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы указываете цвет внутри функции `aes()`. Это приводит к тому, что указанный вами текст интерпретируется как текстовая константа, а цвет опеределяется исходя из установленой темы, как если бы вы использвовали в качестве аргумента к `fill` указали одну из переменных вашего датафрейма и использовали `scale_fill_*`.

Вы также можете увидеть это по легенде в которой указано "darkorange".

Для того чтобы указать цвета для слоя, а не привязать его к теме - указывайте `fill = "darkorange"` вне вызова `aes()`

Comment: Я сделал ggplot(data=USmelanoma, aes(x=mortality))+geom_density()++theme_dark()+fill('darkorange'). Нет такой команды 'fill'. Не понимаю где.

Comment: fill это аргумент к geom_density, просто в данном случае не нужно его обрамлять в aes